# Will the 12.04.1 ISO appear on the Ubuntu website?

Tags: release-management, maintenance

Following the release schedule for 12.04 [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule), I see that today, the 12.04.1 maintenance release will come out. Since it includes all updates found for 12.04 up until today and saves me a lot of bandwidth and time, how will I know I am downloading the 12.04.1 if it comes out today.

For example, the only clue right now is the part about `Precise 12.04.1 includes the Ubuntu 3.2.0-29.46 kernel.` which is mentioned in the Kernel section in [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)

but apart from that I do not know if it is a torrent/iso with the 12.04.1 name on it, or the 12.04 but implying that the updates are included already. For example a desktop-12.04-64bit.iso that includes all 12.04.1 or a desktop-12.04.1-64bit.iso that mentions the ".1" so I know it is the maintenance release.

Will it appear in the website as 12.04.1 so I know it is the maintenance release or it is assumed that from the 23rd of August the torrent/iso downloaded is the 12.04.1 even though it only mentions it as 12.04?

Sorry for the confusion, just want to be sure since it involves me, my "very fast" bandwidth and the amount of hours for it to download.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The website has been updated to show you are downloading the 12.04.1 ISO (see red box below):

  [image]
- The ISOs, torrents, etc. are all are explicitly named `ubuntu-12.04.1-...`, if you wish to confirm that you are downloading 12.04.1:

  [image]
- Remember that anything named 12.04 *is* 12.04, **not** 12.04.1!

Comment: Yeah I was wondering about 10.04. Thanks for the link.