# Ubuntu 12.04.1 ready?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do maintenance releases appear in the Ubuntu website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179459/do-maintenance-releases-appear-in-the-ubuntu-website)

I'm trying to see if the first point release 12.04.1 is ready, but I can't tell from the Ubuntu web site. I'm running 10.04 in some labs and according to Ubuntu we should wait for the first point release before we upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to answer this question in a lasting way. As of Aug. 23, 17:15:32 UTC, the bits are not available.

Run `do-release-upgrade -c` to check.

**Update**

By the way, according to [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts) `do-release-upgrade -c` will output "No new release found" until 12.04.1 is available, even if you're on 10.04.x. This is because 12.04 is considered a devel release.

As of Aug. 23, 19:21:03 UTC, I'm seeing "New release 'precise' available" which I assume refers to 12.04.1.

Comment: Thanks. The -c option doesn't seem to be documented in the man page.

Comment: Yeah I only discovered this via `do-release-upgrade -h`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using 10.4, and 12.4.1 has finally appeared in Update Manager. I had to set the settings to "LTS Releases only" or it only showed 10.10. Now I upgrade.

Comment: Add a comment here about how the upgrade goes.

Answer (score 0):

I intially though this had already been released, and I have been corrected. The .1 version has only been out since August 17.  (I was told by several people that it was out far before that -- I'm sorry that my information was incorrect.)

I found this sub-domain of Ubuntu's site that shows current and past releases of Ubuntu: http://releases.ubuntu.com/

You can update via Terminal by following this tutorial: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/upgrade-to-ubuntu-12-04-from-ubuntu-10-04-via-the-terminal/

Comment: xx.xx.x updates are similar to the service packs of windows.

Answer (score 0):

12.04.1 has been ready since August 17 http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/
Thought a torrent download became available just on August 23.

Comment: Thanks. Its funny though that the main ubuntu web site didn't say it until today. Now ubuntu.com main says explicitly that "12.04.1 is here."